# How to lapply() a formula over a dataframe list. or how to perform kruskal.test() over a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, kruskal-wallis

So I have this Data and trying to do `kruskal.test()` over a list containing dataframes

```
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L

    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
       "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    )
)
```

I am trying to perform `kruskal.test` over these 3 dataframes but failed after hours and hours of trying to find a solution. I am new to R.

Failed attempts are :

```
snake <- function(i){
  kruskal.test(df$Height ~ df$Person, data = i)
}
snail <- lapply(df_list, "[[", snake)


df_list %>% kruskal.test(df$Height ~ df$Person)

sapply(df_list, function(i) { kruskal.test(df$Height ~ df$Person, data = i)})


Map(function(x) kruskal.test(Height ~ Person), get(df_list))

Map(function(df_list, .f(kruskal.test(Height ~ Person)))

lapply(mget(df_list), function(x) kruskal.test(Height ~ Person))

bunny <- df_list %>%
  kruskal_test(df$Height ~ Person, data = .)
```

Summary: I am trying to do `kruskal.test()` over a set of list containing dataframes. How can a pass a formula over `lapply()` or `Map()` to run the `kruskal.test()` in each dataframes in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is referencing an object called "df", which does not appear to exist. Also, when using `kruskal.test` with the arguments `kruskal.test(formula, data)`, there is no need to reference the data frame in the formula. Providing `kruskal.test` a "data" argument will cause the function to search for the formula symbols first in the provided data. In other words, if data frame "x" contains columns "Height" and "Person", then the following would work:

```
kruskal.test(Height ~ Person, data = x)
```

In your example, you shouldn't reference `df`. Notice that the code below creates a temporary function with an argument called "i", and that "i" is subsequently referenced:

```
lapply(df_list, function(i) kruskal.test(Height ~ Person, data = i))

$`1.3.A`

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Height by Person
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 5, df = 2, p-value = 0.08208


$`2.2.A`

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Height by Person
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 5, df = 2, p-value = 0.08208


$`1.1.B`

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Height by Person
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 5, df = 2, p-value = 0.08208
```

Comment: Purrr/Tidyverse version: `map(df_list, ~kruskal.test(Height ~ Person, data = .))
`

Comment: @jdobres Thank you very much!! You are a life saver!! In my head, I was referencing the list. Thank you very for the explanation. Right now, I am having a hard time when or when not to reference a particular argument in a given function in R.

Comment: @andrew_reece, Thank you for this solution as well. :)